# Android Studio's Android emulator will not start.

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, react-native, android-emulator

After installing Android Studio, I initially started it up to see how it works. It started up like normal, and I closed it. After starting a react native project and trying to open it with `react-native run-android` , I am told to have an Android device running first, so I go back to android studio to open the emulator, and when I launch an emulator, a bar in Android Studio will fill up like so.

[image: Android studio will do this but go no further.]

However, when the bar fills up all the way, nothing happens. I've made sure I have the proper folders in the System variables as ANDROID_HOME, the emulator ran once before, so what's the deal? I even tried deleting the virtual device and creating a new one, and uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator part of the Studio program. Also I opened up a new project in Android Studio and had it run using my AVD. After having the "Starting AVD" bar fill up, I get a bar saying that Studio is waiting for the device to start up, infinitely.

[image]

Nothing else on the Internet is helping, and I can't launch it from the command line because emulator is not being recognized as a command despite me triple checking the correct folders are in the path. Any ideas what is causing this? I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Have you enabled **intel haxm** in bios? And you need to create a emulator in **AVD Manager**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem...
What I did and what helped:
**1)** Remove Android Studio from your Computer
**2)** Reinstall it on your Device

Comment: Thanks, completely uninstalling every part of Android Studio, including the SKD stuff got the emulators to start up.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:
1. Open AVD for editing
2. "Graphisc: Automatic" change to "Hardware - ..."

Comment: Good hint. Hardware didn't work for me, but Software did!

Answer (score 1):

My issue was my workflow on the default virtual devices. I would always click the power button before closing the emulator. Because the Boot option is set to `Quick boot` by default, it started the virtual device in its last state, which was powered off. I deleted all my virtual devices, created a new one, clicked advanced settings and set the Boot option to `Cold boot` in the Emulated Performance section.
Using Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

firstly,you have check that CPU virtulization is enable or not. if not then enable that from BIOS setting.

Answer (score 0):

Since your emulator ran first and now its not working. Try this

1. click on **avd manager.**
2. select your virtual device which you want to run and in extreme right
   there will be **"pencil sign**" to edit the virtual device click on it.
3. **show advance setting** , scroll to Ram (option) and set it to 512.
4. Now run.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 only need to uninstall Android Studio, restart machine and install again, everything works fine, no need to remove SDK!